# Is there a way to customize classic windows appearance futher than the built in software allows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop-customization, color-profiles

Specifically I'd like to customize the single pixel wide "rims" outlining each window box.

I think the purpose of them is to create a 3d effect, but I find them too contrasty and distracting.

If possible I'd like to get rid of them entirely, as well as the shadows, leaving my windows looking flat, but I'd also be happy with the ability to change the border types. The more robust the solution the better actually.

[image]

Comment: There's a product called WindowBlinds 8 from Stardock. Despite the name, it works on Win 7 as well. I don't know if it can do exactly this, but if it can't, probably nothing can. (No connection except as a satisfied customer.) https://store.stardock.com/product/ESD-SDS-W1222

Comment: I've purchased this software in the past. As far as I can tell, it just mocks up the look of whatever the next generation of windows is, at the expense of resources.  They wouldn't give me my money back. But that means I can still get my licensed software from them. So I'll give it another look. Thanks for the advice.